# Can't display alert dialog on button click Android

Tags: java, android, dialog, alert

So I created a multiple choice alert dialog. The problem is that I can't display it. I want to display it when the user clicks on a button in another Activity. Here is the code.

```
public class FlourishPickerDialog extends DialogFragment {
    public ArrayList<String> flourishSet = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final ArrayList mSelectedItems = new ArrayList();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.flourish_picker_text)
                .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.dealersGripFlourishArr, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            mSelectedItems.add(which);
                        } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {
                            mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                        }
                    }
                })

                .setPositiveButton(R.string.create, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public  void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        flourishSet = mSelectedItems;
                    }
                })

                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
        builder.create();
        return builder.show();
    }

}
```

So how can I do that? I tried creating a method in the activity and calling it with a button onClick but I couldn't. Thanks in advance.
EDIT :

I also tried typing builder.show(); before builder.create(); and reverse.
Here is how I try to display it. This is the method in the activity.java of the xml file with the button onClick.

```
public void showFlourishPicker() {
    DialogFragment alert = new FlourishPickerDialog();
    alert.show(getFragmentManager(), "flourishes");
}
```

EDIT 2:

Here is the xml onClick

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="showFlourishPicker"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="86dp" />
```

Comment: What is the error given

Comment: No error while compiling. When I click the button it says App stopped working.

Comment: Post the code where you actually handle the button click event + Your stack trace

Comment: Add a contructor on your DialogFragment class `public FlourishPickerDialog(){}`

Comment: And call it when you intercept the onClick method this way: `new FlourishPickerDialog().show(getFragmentManager(), "Tag");`

Comment: your code is fine. How are you calling this dialog, post that code in your question

Comment: All of your code related to dialog is fine. Have you check that button click listener is working fine.

Comment: and have you set `android:onclick=showFlourishPicker` in your XML layout?

Comment: Are you on Activity?

Comment: Yeah I have set the onClick in the xml

Comment: are you using v4 DialogFragment ?

Comment: For god sake just show us the activity's code. (where you handle the click event)

Comment: There you go. The alert dialog is in another class. I want to call it from the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your problem and I got the solution, follow those steps.

On your `MainActivity` import this :

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

Make your call as follows :

```
public void showFlourishPicker (View v){
  DialogFragment alert = new FlourishPickerDialog();
  alert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "flourishes");
}
```

And in your `FlourishPicker` add this imports :

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

Comment: @Codearts Are you sing AppCompatActivity, Fragment, FragmentActivity...? What are you using?

Comment: I am using AppCompatActivity, Fragment but I am not using FragmentActivity. This is where I was learning from. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html
It's described really well as you could expect but for reasons I can't see yet it doesn't work.

Comment: Easy on the downvotes ! This answer seems legit, what's wrong with it ?

Comment: Skizo you are the man. Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot man! Made my day. :)

Comment: You are welcome @Codearts, remember, when you use the `onClick:` attribute you **must** add `View v` as a parameter of the void, otherwise it will crash :)

Comment: Or you can just use the debugger next time and see what's the issue.

Comment: @JDev No no, I know it was him, because somebody downvoted him :S

Answer (score 1):

Remove the show code from your dialog and place it in the calling activity.
And in the onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) method return builder.create();

onCreateDialog has to return Dialog but show() returns void.

Comment: builder.show() returns an alertDialog. It's basically the same, except for the dialog's visibilty part.

Comment: @JDev didn't know that, will try it out.